# How can i delete message that channel name was changed using telebot?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

I wrote a bot that change name of the telegram channel every N minutes
But, when name of the channel is changed telegram automaticly send message, that channel name has been changed

i tried `bot.delete_message` command, but could't figure out how to delete that exact message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete the message that Telegram sends automatically when the channel name is changed, you can use the **channel_post_handler** decorator provided by the Telebot library to intercept and delete these messages.

Example:
**bot.py**

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('BOT_TOKEN')


@bot.channel_post_handler(content_types=['new_chat_title'])
def channel_name_changed(message):
    try:
        bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error deleting message:", e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling()
```

**changer.py**

```
import random
from time import sleep

import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('BOT_TOKEN')


def change_channel_name():
    new_name = random.choice(["Channel 1", "Channel 2", "Channel 3", "Channel 4", "Channel 5"])
    try:
        bot.set_chat_title(
            "@CHAT",
            new_name
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error changing channel name:", e)


def main():
    while True:
        change_channel_name()
        sleep(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, working as intended. But from this situation appeard new question - can i somehow change the name of the super group with the same bot or i should write another one?

Comment: @SADLAD You need to change the message handler to @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['new_chat_title']). This will work fine.